# passing a dynamic html table to php as an array

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamic html table( rows are added dynamically using java script) and I want to pass whole table to a php script as an array.Is there a way to insert the table data to an array?
I have tried using phpTableExtractor but it dosen't extract dynamically added rows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any other reliable solution but creating a HTML form along with the table and have the user click a submit button to save the table. Then you can read all content from `$_POST` and store it in a database.

Another solution would be to use AJAX requests to store the table content every time the focus changes or something like that. Will make your page dependent on JavaScript though.

Answer (score 1):

What if you fill a JS array at the same time you create the table?
You will use the html just for display but behind you have the data you send to php.